# ASP.NET - Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess call back with params

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, callback

I want to add more params to my OnSuccess call back (**but keep the ajax context variable**).
What I did is:

```
 using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", new AjaxOptions() {
   OnSuccess = "new function(arg){HandleBasicForm(arg , 'MyCustomVariable')}",
    ...
```

The JS function:

```
function HandleBasicForm(ajaxContext , myCustomVariable){
            var content = ajaxContext.get_response().get_object();
            ....
        }
```

But `ajaxContext` is null.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since you're using `get_response()` I'm guessing that you're not using the unobtrusive javascript stuff (in MVC3 you've set `HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false`) and you're referencing the MicrosoftAjax,js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js files. If that's the case you just need to drop the `new` keyword.

```
 using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "function(arg){HandleBasicForm(arg , 'MyCustomVariable')}"})
```

If you are using the MVC3 unobtrusive javascript support with jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js then you can use the implicitly available `xhr` and `data` variables instead.

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "HandleBasicForm(data, 'MyCustomVariable')"})
```

In your handler there would be no need to use `get_response().get_object()` since the deserialized JSON data would be passed in to your handler directly.

```
function HandleBasicForm(data, myCustomVariable){
    var someValue = data.someProperty; //work with data object returned
    ....
}
```

Comment: I'm not following how you're supposed to use the "data" parameter. It just throws an exception for me saying "data is not defined".

Comment: @rossisdead I know this is old, but I know many may be wondering the same thing. The `data` parameter is what is returned from the server, generally an MVC or Web API controller. This result can be returned as a `JsonResult` or simply `Json` and you can access properties of that object from the result.

Comment: @BarryTormey what if i am returning the `PartialViewModel` and i need access to some of its property ?

Answer (score 11):

`OnSuccess` receives `data, status, xhr` from the server:

```
OnSuccess = "myJsMethod(data, status, xhr)"
```

And then its equivalent JavaScript method would be:

```
 function myJsMethod(data, status, xhr) {
}
```

Now your controller should return:

```
return Json(new { param1 = 1, param2 = 2, ... }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then in `myJsMethod` you will have access to `data.param1` and so on.

Comment: Where can I find the source for this information? What are the standard parameters for OnFailure for example?

Comment: Take a loot at its source code @github: https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive