# How to get data returned by Action after ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

There is `PartialView` for `HttpGet` Method in my controller. and for `httpPost` I'm returning `JsonResult` . I am submitting ajax form but unable to get Json data after form submit.
This is my controller code

```
        [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult EditStudent(int Id)
        {
            var getStudent = _db.Student.Find(Id);
            if (getStudent != null)
            {
                return PartialView("EditStudent", getStudent);
            }
            return PartialView("EditStudent");
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult EditStudent(Student st)
        {
            var getData = _db.Student.Find(st.Id);
            getData.Name = st.Name;
            getData.Class = st.Class;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            IList<Student> getSt = _db.Student.ToList();
            return Json(getSt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is my partialView Page Code

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditStudent", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "dv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "**BindSt**()" }))
        {
            <div class="modal-body">
                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                                Student Name
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "txtStName" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Student Class
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Class, new { id = "txtStClass" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id) is Invalid Id</span>
                }
            </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class "btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
        </div>
        }
```

As you can see I want to call **BindSt()** function which is written in my js.

This is my bindst function

```
function BindSt(data) {
            var tblHtml = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                tblHtml += "<tr><td>" + d.Id + "</td><td>" + d.Name + "</td><td>" + d.Class + "</td><td><img src='../../Images/edit.jpg' style='width:25px;cursor:pointer;height:25px;' class='dvEdit'/> &nbsp; <img src='../../Images/Delete.png' style='width:25px;cursor:pointer;height:25px;' class='dvDelete' /></td></tr>";
            });
            $('#tblst').find('tbody').html(tblHtml);
        }
```

but my bindst function need a paramter data . and my action **EditStudent** returning json which i want to pass in that . how can i do that data so that i can pass in that function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET - Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess call back with params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034530/asp-net-ajax-beginform-onsuccess-call-back-with-params)

Comment: @AmanBaloch:I did that but the Bind() is not called onsuccess.

Comment: Have you tried  OnSuccess = "BindSt(data)"

Comment: You are missing St in function name when assigning. You need to set OnSuccess = "BindSt(data)"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034530/asp-net-ajax-beginform-onsuccess-call-back-with-params