# ASP.NET Success Callback with HTML.BeginForm()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I need to add functionality to an existing form in ASP.NET. I would like to fire a Javascript function after the existing validations have cleared and the form is submitted and change as little of the existing code as possible.

My question:
Is there a success callback with `HTML.BeginForm()`?
I am trying to replicate the functionality from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8036779/3100284) which uses `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

My constraints:
All of the validation and rendering is already in place, so I would like to do this with `HTML.BeginForm()` instead of `Ajax.BeginForm()` at the view level without messing with the controller at all, if possible.

Existing form:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Location", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="clearfix">
            <input type="hidden" name="Member.Page" value="@(ViewBag.PageType)" />
            <input id="inputMemberType" type="hidden" name="Member.Type" value="@(Enumeration.Subscription.Global)" />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Member.Email, new { id = "textEmail", @class = "left", placeholder =  (LanguageManager.GetText(LanguageConst.SIGNUP_PH_EMAIL)) })
            <input id="buttonSignUp" type="submit" class="left" value="@(LanguageManager.GetText(LanguageConst.SIGNUP_BTN_SIGNUP))" />
            <div class="left">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Member.Email, string.Empty, new { @class = "container-error", style = "color:white;" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

I am rather unfamiliar with ASP.NET, so any help is appreciated.

Related:
[BeginForm Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Have you tried adding an `onsubmit ` attribute in the `htmlAttributes` parameter?

Comment: Why do you want to fire a javascript on form post? Actually, after the form is posted the user will be redirected to an `action` url. It looks like all HTML manipulations are useless after it.