# MVC - PartialView not updated after Ajax POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Within this application I've been given to work with, a partial view '**MessageForm**' has a simple Ajax form like so:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("", "", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "addForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message) //displays "Hello"
}
```

When the form is submitted, the **ChangeMessage** function on the controller is called:

```
$('#addForm').submit(function () {
    var formdata = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("addForm")); 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '@Url.Action("ChangeMessage")');
    xhr.send(formdata);
    return false;
});
```

This ChangeMessage() method simply modifies the Message property in the model, and returns the same partial view again:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult ChangeMessage(MessageModel model)
{
    model.Message = "Goodbye";
    return PartialView("MessageForm", model);
}
```

The message is updated to "Goodbye" in the model correctly (I've debugged the view), but it is **not** displayed in the output, the output HTML still shows "Hello" when the view is returned. The following line within the form is still outputting this old message:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message) //correct when debugged as "Goodbye", but still displaying "Hello" in the browser
```

It's as if the view has been rendered again, but with no actual output.

Very new to Ajax, so it's most likely I've misunderstood something here?

Comment: You need to replace the HTML content on the page with what is returned from the server. That doesn't happen magically.

Comment: The @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message) line is executed again with the updated value. Obviously my understanding is incorrect, but that would cater for magic.

Comment: You have to tell the ajax call what to do on success. Check out this question for more detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034530/asp-net-ajax-beginform-onsuccess-call-back-with-params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ajax.BeginForm helper is part of the Microsoft Unobtrusive Ajax library, but you're not using it completely.  Ensure you've done the following:

1. Add the Javascript library: `Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`
2. Ensure the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file is referenced by your layout

With the `@Ajax.BeginForm`, you need to specify an `AjaxOptions` telling it what to do with the response.  In your case, I suspect you want to replace the contents of the form with the result:

```
<div id="myform">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeMessage", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myform" }))
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Message)
        <input type="submit" />
    }
</div>
```

You don't need your Javascript for submitting the form using jquery - the unobtrusive library does this for you.

Finally, you need to modify your ChangeMessage view as LabelFor will only display the field name, not the contents of the model.

Comment: It finally works, and that makes a lot more sense - thank you.