# Passing viewmodel between partial views MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a main view and two partial views. I need to be able to populate the viewmodel with the values in my first partial view and pass the viewmodel to the second partial view on click of the button. The button is in the second partial view. I have written a javascript function to do that but the viewmodel is empty when I check the controller method. As you you can see in the screenshot below the services box is the second partial view

**First Partial view**

[image]

**Second Partial View**

```
@model CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.NewRequestViewModel

<div id="NewRequest">
    <h1>Services</h1>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%" } })

        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="mapInit()" />
    }


</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function mapInit() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Service", "request")',
            // datatype: "json",
            data: $('form').serialize(), // update this
            type: "POST",
            // contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });
    }


</script>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Service(NewRequestViewModel model)
{
    return PartialView("_NewService", model);
}
```

Comment: Issuing an AJAX request is a *totally separate* request-response cycle, completely divorced from what happened server-side during the initial view rendering. If you need information there, you must either post it along with the AJAX request or rebuild it there.

Comment: Sorry chris. I didnt understand you. COuld you give me an example

Comment: I can see the view model values in controller however on the client side when i do an alert to check the model data it shows blank

Comment: Another thing what I noticed is that I dont have any element in my view called form. Do you think that would be the reason

Comment: Your Form element should be wrapped around the entirety of the page, aka the View itself instead of individually within Partial Views.  That is unless your Partial Views are performing some sort of submit each.  Also, you could set the Model up in the View itself, then trickle down into each Partial View with that same Model.

Comment: I would be having a submit in each partial view

Comment: Also I have refenced the viewmodel in each of my partial view @model CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.NewRequestViewModel

Comment: submit button should be out side of the second partial view .because when you click on button,you will take first partial view data and pass to second partial view at that time you need to refresh the second partial view.

Comment: that why you have to put submit button outside of the partial view

Comment: You should remove the javascript from the partial view. This can cause issues. I also agree that you should remove the submit button from the partial view as well. You can create a javascript function that posts the data from the first form (partial 1) to the server and updates partial 2 when the button is clicked. This would be how I would approach your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion to you how to resolve your task:

1. You have to change the type of your button on the Second partial view form to the button type: `<input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="mapInit()" />` This step is necessary not to clean your form when an original submit-event works out after your ajax method.
2. In your mapInit function you should add a property `success` and write a function there to update your Second partial form by hand this way:

   ```
   function mapInit() {
       $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("Service", "request")',
           // datatype: "json",
           data: $('form').serialize(), // update this
           type: "POST",
           success: function (data)
           {
               var html = $(data).find('form').html();
               $('#NewRequest').find('form').html(html);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Thus, providing that your First partial form has the same fields, you'll be able to fill your second form with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a get or post action for your partial view.This will get your posted model as parameter and returns second partial view.

2) Modify the BeginForm field of partial view in UI and add OnSuccess event.(eg [Handel OnSuccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8036779/4723876))

3) Create Jquery method to get request on success and replace the first partial view content with second one in UI.(eg: $('#PartialView1Container').html(result);)